# How do I save the state of a Collapsible Panel to a session variable?

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm an experienced OOP programmer, but new to LAMP and Laravel.

I have a page that has a series of collapsible panels.  A user might be have two panels open, and 8 collapsed.  If they refresh the screen to view a new record, all panels revert back to their default open/collapsed state.

How can I save the state of the panels, and reset each panel to it's most recent open or collapsed state?

Just so we're clear about what I'm referring to, here's a simplified version of one of my panels.  Critiques and suggestions are welcomed.  Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse9">Allocations</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
           Here is my title
        </div>
      </div>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse9" class="panel-collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">Reserved for future functionality
        here is my content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Refreshing the page refreshes the HTML, which sets the default shown/hidden state of the panels (controlled by a CSS class). You can save that state in PHP's `session` logic, but you'd need a unique identifier for each panel, a `session` entry for each, and logic to change that session variable via a JavaScript event listener. It's a little broad of a concept for Stackoverflow as it is currently written.

Comment: If you want to save state, you need persistent storage. That gives you basically two options: save your data server-side in the session or client-side in HTML5 storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for instance run a ajax request to your backend and save the data using the Session Facade like this:

```
Session::set('yourdata', $value);
```

And access it like this:

```
Session::get('value');
```

You could save the data using javascript to your [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

This is how to save a data to that sessionStorage:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

And you access it like this:

```
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

Comment: I'm already using Session Variables, but I've never used Ajax.  Any suggestions for some starter code, or a resource that I could use to come up to speed?   Total Newbie on Ajax.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JeffBarefoot You basically sent a post to your server without refreshing your site and without having a form, I am going to update my answer with a basic ajax call to the backend